# When can the Big M method lead to a pivot that is unbounded while the problem is infeasible?

Tags: optimization, examples-counterexamples, linear-programming

When applying the Big M method to enter the feasible region, it is possible to have an entering variable that is unbounded, thus the leaving variable cannot be determined. This can happen when the feasible region is unbounded but also when the problem is not feasible. In what circumstances can this happen ? An example of such a behavior ?

Comment: What is this "big M" method ? I know linear programming but I have not been introduced...

Comment: @JeanMarie It is an extension of the Simplex algorithm to find an initial basis, to deal with = constraints for example. You add an artificial variable to the constraint and also to the objective function with -M. M is a very large number that acts as a penalty which force these variables to leave the basis.  When this happens, the simplex entered the feasible region. See this [source](http://www.columbia.edu/~cs2035/courses/ieor3608.F05/david-bigM.pdf) for more information on the method

Comment: Thanks for your rapid answer.